# Consistently rotate a 2d object 45 degrees each steps in C# UNITY

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine, rotation, 2d, degrees

I am trying to make a rotation system for a 2d object. The rotation is controlled by the mouse (rotate the mouse around the object and it is "looking at" the mouse). I have done the system for smooth rotation but I want when the user press shift he can rotate the object more precisely because the object should move at 45 degrees step. I can't figure out how to do it.

I tried a few things to solve it but nothing has achieved me any results. I succeed to make it that when you press shift it rotates the object to the nearest 45-degree angle (0, 45, 90, etc...) which needs to happen one time before it the user can start rotating. But I need help at the actual rotation.

```
//Handle smooth rotating
            if (!Input.GetKey(KeyCode.LeftShift))
            {
               Vector3 mousePos = Camera.main.ScreenToWorldPoint(Input.mousePosition); //Gets the mouse position and converting to world units. 
               transform.rotation = Quaternion.LookRotation(Vector3.forward, mousePos - transform.position);
            }
            else //Handle 45deg rotation
            {
                var vec = transform.eulerAngles;
                vec.z = Mathf.Round(vec.z / 45) * 45;
                transform.eulerAngles = vec;
            }
```

Comment: See [transform.eulerAngles](https://docs.unity3d.com/ScriptReference/Transform-eulerAngles.html) : `Only use this variable to read and set the angles to absolute values. Don't increment them, as it will fail when the angle exceeds 360 degrees. Use Transform.Rotate instead.`

Comment: I created some script before for a similar question. You could reach it from : https://github.com/mucahits/rotateintervally/blob/master/RotateIntervally.cs